# Issue with time variables using strptime

Tags: r, regression

I am currently working on a project and I need some help. I want to predict the length of flight delays, using a statistical model. The data set does not contain the length of flight delays, but it can be calculated from the actual and scheduled departure times.

I will include a link if you want the whole dataset:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11BXmJCB5UGEIRmVkM-yxPb_dHeD2CgXa/view?usp=sharing

I then ran the following code

```
    Delays <- read.table("FlightDelays.csv", header=T, sep=",")
    DepatureTime <- strptime(formatC(Delays$deptime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"), "%H%M")
    ScheduleTime <- strptime(formatC(Delays$schedtime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"), "%H%M")
    DelayTime <- as.numeric(difftime(DepatureTime, ScheduleTime))/60
    DelayData <- data.frame(DelayTime, Delays)
```

The above code allowed me to get the delay time in minutes

For those of you who do not want to obtain the whole dataset I will now include a small example of some observations of the form

```
    structure(list(schedtime = c(1455, 1640, 1245, 1715, 1039 , 2120), deptime = c(1455, 1640, 1245, 1709, 1035, 0010)), .Names = c("schedtime",  "deptime"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and if you run the a code I did at the beginning, the delay in minutes for the 6th observation will be -1270 minutes not a delay of 170 minutes as i believe `strptime` assumes you are still in the same day and doesn't recognise that the delay caused the departure time to be the early hours of the following day.

How can i get the code to recognise the delays will sometimes mean the departure time will go on to the following day?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I can't quite get what the aim is, could you include a copy paste or `dput` of the expected outcome? Also do not readd `sad... in need` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
ScheduleTime <- as_datetime(formatC(Delays$schedtime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"),format="%H%M")
DepatureTime <- as_datetime(formatC(Delays$deptime, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"),format="%H%M") + hours(ifelse(Delays$deptime < Delays$schedtime & Delays$schedtime > 2000,24,0))
DelayTime <- difftime(DepatureTime, ScheduleTime)/60
DelayData <- data.frame(DelayTime, Delays)
```

The Problem is, that you have to decide when it isn't resonable, that a smaller value of `deptime` compared to `schedtime` does not correspond to a day shift, but to a flight leaving early. I don't see a general way around that.